# Error while launch EC2 instance through ubuntu .ssh - Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available(server sent:publickey)

Tags: ssh

Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available(server sent:publickey). I load the .pem file into puttygen and saved public .ppk file. Open putty and browse public.ppk file in auth and  provided elastic ip as public ip but getting below error while login to putty. Any help?